# How can I track for rejected migrations in the SEDE?

Tags: discussion, migration, data-explorer, migration-rejection, moderation-history

I would like to collect the data of the rejected question migrations in the SEDE. I can't see a direct reference to it - the `PostHistoryTypes` table contains only references to the really executed migration events.

Do some non-trivial or indirect way exist to collect the rejected migrations?

Comment: To the extent that this can work at all, its results will suffer severely from survivorship bias, since many rejected migrations end up deleted (from the 12 rejected migrations out of PSE in the past three months, eight are deleted), giving a very skewed vision on the migration pathway. As an example, [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119074/) was rejected from math.se and subsequently deleted, and its id has empty results on both the PostHistory and the Posts tables.

Comment: Wow brain fart on my answer, nevermind. Must be the heat...

Comment: @JasonC Your answer could have been very useful to me, despite the problem E.P. mentioned.